# How to use Collections compare method

Tags: java

I was using the `Comparator` interface to sort the `Person` node variables, but I get several compiler errors. My code is as follows:

```
import java.util.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class ArrayNodeDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

    ArrayList<Person> lstPerson = new ArrayList<Person>();

    Person p1 = new Person();
    p1.setPersonId(1);
    p1.setPersonName("Tom");
    lstPerson.add(p1);

    Person p2 = new Person();
    p2.setPersonId(2);
    p2.setPersonName("Jerry");
    lstPerson.add(p2);

    System.out.println("sorting by Name...");  

    Collections.sort(lstPerson,new NameComparator());  
    Iterator it= lstPerson.iterator();  
    while (it.hasNext()) {  
        Person person=(Person)it.next();  
        System.out.println(person.getPersonId() + " " + person.getPersonName());  
    }  

    System.out.println("sorting by Id...");  

    Collections.sort(lstPerson,new IdComparator());  
    //Iterator it=lstPerson.iterator();  
    while (it.hasNext()) {  
        Person person=(Person)it.next();  
        System.out.println(person.getPersonId() + " " + person.getPersonName());  
    }
```

The following is the Id comparator class:

```
import java.util.*; 

class IdComparator implements Comparator {  
    public int Compare(Person o1, Person o2) {  
        Person p1 = (Person)o1;  
        Person p2 = (Person)o2;  

        if (p1.getPersonId() == p2.getPersonId())  
            return 0;  
        else if (p1.getPersonId() > p2.getPersonId())  
            return 1;  
        else  
            return -1;  
    }  
}
```

And this is the name comparator class;

```
import java.util.*;  

class NameComparator implements Comparator {  
    public int Compare(Person o1, Person o2) {  
        Person p1 = (Person)o1;  
        Person p2 = (Person)o2;  
        return p1.getPersonName().compareTo(p2.getPersonName());  
    }  
}
```

I get the following error, when compile the code:

```
./NameComparator.java:3: error: NameComparator is not abstract and does not override abstract method compare(Object,Object) in Comparator
class NameComparator implements Comparator{  
^
./IdComparator.java:3: error: IdComparator is not abstract and does not override abstract method compare(Object,Object) in Comparator
class IdComparator implements Comparator{  
^
Note: ArrayNodeDemo.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
2 errors
```

Comment: Note its case-sensitive: `Compare` must be in lower case `compare`

Comment: Case sensitive error: method name in java API always starts with small letter

Comment: You have written Compare instead of compare

Comment: use compare() not Compare()..you have typo mistake

Answer (score 3):

You have an error in method name

```
public int Compare(Person o1,Person o2)
```

should be

```
public int compare(Person o1,Person o2)
```

And you need to change this

```
class IdComparator implements Comparator{
```

to this

```
class IdComparator implements Comparator<Person>{
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use generics when implementing comparators.

```
class IdComparator implements Comparator<Person>{
```

and

```
class NameComparator implements Comparator<Person>{
```

Currently you are using raw types, for which there are no compare(Person o1, Person o2) method. Only compare(Object o1, Object o2).

Answer (score 1):

Your Name- and IdComparator klasses implement the 'raw' type Comparator, ie without a type argument. This means they effectively implement `Comparator<Object>` and therefore their compare methods should be `compare(Object o1, Object o2)`.

Make them `implements Comparator<Person>`, add an @Override above the compare methods and write 'compare' (the method name) with a smaller case 'c'. Then your comparators properly implement `Comparator<T>` and your code compiles.

See also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html.

Comment: pardon me as I'm new here... is there a button to signify acceptance?

Comment: A check mark next to the answer actually. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

You need a bit modification in your method,

```
public int compare(Object o1, Object 02)
{
   Person p1 = (Person)o1;
   Person p2 = (Person)o2;
  return p1.getPersonName().compareTo(p2.getPersonName()); 

}
```

The compare method of Comparator takes two Object parameters while your method takes two Person parameters, change the parameters of the method to be Objects or else (and preferably) use a generic Comparator.Generics will give you compile time type checking.e.g,

```
class IdComparator implements Comparator<Person>
```